# y axis label placing on flot chart, JQuery

Tags: jquery, flot

Why is my y axis misplaced and how do I fix it?! I cannot understand why the 'y' axis is on top of the graph. Any thoughts appreciated.

[image]

These are the options that I'm using. I've tried grabbing the generated y-axis class and manually using css to hack it a few pixels to the left but the whole graph just shifts over. As far as I can see there isn't anything in the API that shifts the y axis ticker label relative to the graph.

```
    var options = {
    colors: ["#99CCFF", "#000099", "#FF6C47"],
    series: {
    lines: {show: true, highlightColor:'#000099'},
    points: {show: true}
    },
    xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%d/%m",
    markings: [{color: "#000"}],
    },
    yaxis: {
    markings: [{color: "#000"}]
    },
    grid: {
    markings: [{color: "#fff"}],
    labelMargin: 10,
    axisMargin: 10,
    backgroundColor: {
        colors: [ "#000099", "#29A3CC" ]
    },
    borderWidth: {
        top: 1,
        right: 1,
        bottom: 2,
        left: 2
    }
    },
    legend: {
    show: true,
    backgroundOpacity:.5,
    labelBoxBorderColor: 1,
    position: "nw",
    margin: 5
    }
};
$.plot("#bpTable", [
    {label: "systolic", data: c1},
    {label: "diastolic", data: c2}
],
options);
```

Comment: The picture let's people understand your problem but to help you in solving the issue, you have to provide (parts) of your sourcecode and explain what you tried.

Comment: I guess you are plotting graphs inside hidden div (`<div style=display:none id=bpTable></div>`) are you plotting graphs inside accordion or tabs or something which is not attached to `DOM` when you call `plot`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427725/flot-graph-does-not-render-when-parent-container-is-hidden and especially my last comment on https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1014

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @captain suggested, if you call `$.plot` on a hidden placeholder (bpTable), then this is the result.  Just don't call `$.plot` until your placeholder is visible, or use some trick to render it off screen (i.e. something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5427725/312208)).

Comment: do we have some kind hack or trick if we are using tabs and accordion and plotting graphs inside both? fine if using tabs but what about accordion? I guess this is not a clean solution to delay a plot

Comment: I usually delay the `plot` call until the tab in question is actually shown (using the `activate` event of tabs)

Answer (score 2):

As @Ryley answered already, you have to call $.plot after you show the tab.

When using bootstrap tabs you can attach a handler and call $.plot in it:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == "#umsatz-tab")
    {
        $.plot("#chart", data, options);
    }
});
```

More information on bootstrap tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage (Scroll down to "Events"